# functions not calling correctly in onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, event-handling

I have a button and with this button, I am trying to call two functions but instead, they seem to be cancelling each other out.

In the console it shows this I have numbered them and connected them to the function for example line 1 comes from the console.log in function "addValue".

line 1 - ['Name:  graphqless  Description:    REST and GraphQ… URL:   https://github.com/tylerbuchea/graphqless']

line 2 - []

line - 3 RepoList.js?5216:74 ['Name:  graphqless  Description:    REST and GraphQ… URL:   https://github.com/tylerbuchea/graphqless']
Localstorage is empty.

The desired output is as follows when I click the button, function one should be called and only after clicking again should function 2 be called.

the value is a string

The functions

```
const favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name') || []);




    function addValue(e) {
        if (e.target.value !== "") {
          
          if (!favs.includes(e.target.value)) {
            favs.push(e.target.value);
            localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
//line 1            
console.log(favs);
            document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML =  favs
          }
        }
      }

  





//Check if value is in the array, if it then remove the value from both the array and localstorage
  f

unction removeValue(e, value) {
        if (e.target.value !== "") {
          //delete from array
          favs.pop(e.target.value);
//line 2          
console.log(favs);
          //change the div text
          document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML = favs;
          //get the values from localstorage- parse
          const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
          //delete the value
          delete stored[(value, e.target.value)];
          //store the new array as a string
          localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
//line 3          
console.log(stored);
        }
      }
```

This is how I am calling the function

```
onClick={(e)=> {addValue(e); removeValue(e);}}
```

Comment: well you call both at the same time. If you want to toggle, you are going to have to add sum logic to figure out what state it is in.

Comment: Your event handler is calling both functions. It won't magically alternate between them on its own, you have to actually write code that does this.

Comment: Also note that it's `const favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name') || "[]");` (quotes around the empty array) or you'll be calling `JSON.parse([])` at some point which won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add logic to determines the state. Somehow you need a boolean to know what state you are in. so either you flip a boolean variable or you add remove a class.

Using a Boolean

```js
function doAdd(elem) {
  console.log("add called", elem);
}

function doRemove(elem) {
  console.log("remove called", elem);
}

let actionSate = false;
function doAction(e) {
  const elem = e.currentTarget;
  actionSate = !actionSate;
  if (actionSate) {
    doAdd(elem);
  } else {
    doRemove(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="doAction(event)">Click</button>
```

Using a class allows you to have more than one trigger. Each one can work by themselves.

```js
function doAdd(elem) {
  console.log("add called", elem);
}

function doRemove(elem) {
  console.log("remove called", elem);
}


function doAction(e) {
  const elem = e.currentTarget;
  elem.classList.toggle("action");
  if (elem.classList.contains("action")) {
    doAdd(elem);
  } else {
    doRemove(elem);
  }
}
```

```css
.action {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="doAction(event)">Click 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="doAction(event)">Click 2</button>
```

Comment: can you do that with hooks? im trying now by using  a boolean hook and i keep getting an error.

Comment: So set the state in react and check what the state is.

Comment: it's set as false but error it's flagging is in the addValue function where it says e.target.value !== ""